Запуск с сохранением авторизации на сайтах selenium
Я пишу код который будет раз в какое-то время запускать сайт, дело в том что на нём авторизация через дискорд и чтобы действие выполнилось я должен уже быть в аккаунте на сайте.
Текущий код запускает от нового пользователя
import time
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("https://discordserver.info/1082180028151906316/like")

Я видел вариант что можно добавить параметры для запуска с профиля
chrome_options.add_argument("--profile-directory=Profile 3")

Такой вариант запускает также без входа в аккаунт
chrome_options.add_argument("--user-data-dir=C:\\Users\\Кирилл\\AppData\\Local\\Google\\Chrome\\User Data")  # Путь к вашему профилю Chrome
chrome_options.add_argument("--profile-directory=Profile 3")

А такой вариант уже входит в нужный профиль но не открывает сайт
Кто-то может помочь разобраться?
P.S. Ещё нужно чтобы оно запускалось в фоновом режиме

Аргументы, которые помогут решить ваш вопрос:
user-data-dir=PATH – Указывает расположение папки с профилями.
--profile-directory=Profile 1 – Задает папку профиля, по умолчанию стоит Default.
--allow-profiles-outside-user-dir – Позволяет указать кастомное расположение папки с профилями.
from time import sleep
from selenium import webdriver
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
chrome_options.add_argument('--allow-profiles-outside-user-dir')
chrome_options.add_argument('--enable-profile-shortcut-manager')
chrome_options.add_argument(r'user-data-dir=.\User')
chrome_options.add_argument('--profile-directory=Profile 1')

driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path="C:\\Users\\chromedriver.exe", chrome_options=chrome_options) 
driver.get("https://discordserver.info/1082180028151906316/like")
sleep(120)
print("Close")

После включения данных аргументов, данные будут сохранятся в папку User
рядом с проектом и после каждого перезапуска будут подгружаться chrome-мом.
Дополнительная информация:

Стандартный профиль chrome-а не удается использовать в  headless режиме и наоборот.

Если надо пройти двухфакторную аутентификацию на сайте через headless chrome, то можно добавить следующий аргумент:--remote-debugging-port=9222
Он поднимет удаленный сервер по адресу localhost:9222 через который можно управлять headless chrome-мом.

При отключении детекта chromedriver-а ( аргумент: --disable-blink-features=AutomationControlled), chrome перестал сохранять данные профиля. Помогли исправить ситуацию следующие аргументы:
--profiling-flush=n – сбрасывает данные профиля в файл через n-ое число секунд.
--enable-aggressive-domstorage-flushing – минимизирует потерю данных.


Также возможно это вам поможет:
https://m.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLqGS6O1-DZLp1kgiQNpueIMCHRNzgHa1r,
https://qna.habr.com/q/1330430,
https://codeby.net/threads/metody-obxoda-zaschity-ot-avtomatizirovannogo-po-v-brauzere-chrome-pod-upravleniem-selenium-v-python.81358/.

Комментарии были перемещены в чат; пожалуйста, не продолжайте дискуссию здесь. Прежде чем разместить комментарий ниже этого, пожалуйста, ознакомьтесь с назначением комментариев. Комментарии, которые не запрашивают уточнения или не предлагают улучшения, скорее всего должны быть ответами, размещены на [meta] или написаны в [chat]. Комментарии, продолжающие дискуссию, могут быть удалены.
